# How to select to end of word in intellij-idea / phpstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, phpstorm

Is there a way to expand a selection to the end of the current word in intellij idea / phpstorm?

For example (ASCII art ahead...)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
      <----------------------->|
```

I have an existing selection from the start of "ipsum" to part-way through "consectetuer". How do I select to the end of that word. Pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+Right` takes me to the beginning of adipiscing. This is not a big deal when the spacing is small but sometimes it looks more like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer          adipiscing elit.
      <----------------------->|
```

And I have two choices... either `Right` to the end of the current word, or `CTRL+SHIFT+Right` to the beginning of adipiscing and then `Left` back to where I want to be.

Most other text editors/IDEs I've used select to the end of the current word. Hopefully there's a settings I cannot find to do the same in PHP Storm!

In the settings there's just the existing `CTRL+SHIFT+Right` mapped to "Move Caret to Next Word with Selection" and I cannot find any settings anywhere to change this.

Comment: Didn't use phpstorm for some time but did you try ctrl+w ? Maybe with shift, not sure.

Comment: It looks like this feature has now been added by IntelliJ and will be released soon.

Comment: the emacsIDEAs plugin do it in another way.  firstly, you jump to i of the 'ipsum',  then using the jump selection(C-I C-I) action to jump to space after the 'consectetuer'.

Comment: Having used it for a while, I actually now quite like the CTRL-W functionality to progressively expand the selection. The only problem is that it's CTRL-W which is "close window" in every other app, so now that I've tested it out and like it, I've got to unlearn the shortcut and assign a new keystroke!

Comment: **Lets vote for the ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5365**, and, may be, someday the ticket will be solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no separate action that would just extend selection to the "word end", only to the "next word". There is one that would "delete" to the end of the word but nothing for "selection".

[This ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211369/) seems to be asking what you need -- star/vote/comment to get notified on any progress. Since it is in backlog section and has no votes at the moment, I doubt that it is in dev's TODO shortlist.

If that ticket is not what you need, feel free to submit [new Feature Request ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

**P.S.** Have you tried **ideaVim** or **emacsIDEAs** plugins? AFAIK they may (should) support such action.

---

**UPDATE 2022-12-30:**
The aforementioned [IDEA-211369 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211369/) has been implemented in the 2019.2 version. The behaviour should be controlled by the `Caret Movement | When moving by words` option in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (I'm astounded that more people don't miss this functionality... I'd guess it's more of a function of the difficulty of searching IDEA's forums and tagging things than lack of need). I have no idea how to use VIM or emacs, so those plugins would probably be more hindrance than help. Then again, maybe it's about time I learnt how to use VI/VIM for extra geek kudos...

Comment: This is one of those features a lot of people would like to have but wouldn't bother to pursue if not already there. Unfortunately Jetbrains won't bother with "trivial" features like this unless there's a massive amount of upvotes, and still they'll take ages to respond, no matter how trivial the fix. No doubt they're busy with more important stuff, yet consistent cursor movement is extremely important in my book, and to date, ⌥← → movements on IntelliJ are inconsistent with all other editors on `OSX`. Good news is it should be easy to create a plugin to add the missing cursor movements.

Comment: ideaVim does indeed support the navigation as described, [alas it messes with a lot of shortcuts I am used to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351405/how-to-enable-vim-mode-shortcuts-only-for-navigation-in-ideavim-plugin).