# How to enable vim-mode shortcuts only for navigation in IdeaVim plugin?

Tags: vim, configuration, phpstorm, intellij-13, ideavim

I want to use the IdeaVim plugin, yet currently only the parts of the navigation.

This means I want to be able to navigate the file using the <kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd> keys or use the <kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd>.

Yet as soon as when I enter insert mode I want all the shortcuts to still be PhpStom's.

Also it would be nice to toggle IdeaVim on/off via shortcut, for the transition process while I am learning vim shortcuts.

I did not found way to configure it this way. Can I achieve this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Normal mode of IdeaVim only with other modes, including the Insert mode. As for the shortcut to toggle the Vim emulation, you can assign your own shortcut for that in Settings | Keymap.